# For ElasticSearch-1.5.2 royrusso-elasticsearch monitoring tool is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any free monitoring tool available for ElasticSerach-1.5.2 ? Royrusso-elasticsearch monitoring tool is not supporting in that version.Please suggest..

Comment: You have a few plugins [available here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html#site) that you might want to try.

Comment: I tried every plugin @Val ji...but non is working.I want to monitor the cluster status for elasticsearch-1.5.2 in Royrusso-elasticsearch monitoring tool.If any free tool like this,we can monitor the cluster status for that mentioned version of ES..Please suggest.

Comment: Many thanks Sir.Elasticsearch HQ (by Roy Russo) plugin is working fine.Thanks again :)